# Here in the context below I use past and future tense together in one sentence. Is it wrong?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Do watch this movie. It won't leave you disappointed and the closure of this film truly lived up to the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

> It won't leave you disappointed and the closure of this film truly lived up to the expectation.

Note that **[expectation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expectation)** is normally used in the plural.

In the first clause, **won't** is an abbreviation for **will not** (future tense), so you are actually mixing future and past. It is perfectly OK, and often happens, that you use different tenses in different clauses of a sentence... as long as you use the right tenses.

There are several possibilities, depending on the exact meaning of **expectations**. If you are talking about your own expectations, past tense is fine, because you have already seen the film:

> It won't leave you disappointed, and the closure of this film truly **lived** up to **my** expectations.

If you are talking about the expectations of the person you are talking to, you must use future tense, because they will see the film in the future.

> It won't leave you disappointed, and the closure of this film **will** truly live up to **your** expectations.

If you are talking about the expectations of people in general, you are talking about a universal truth- something that was true, is true, and always will be true. You use present tense to talk about universal truths, for example

> water **boils** at 100 degrees

Your sentence referring to people in general would therefore be

> It won't leave you disappointed, and the closure of this film truly **lives** up to expectations.

Comment: ... any particular reason for the downvote?